# How do i hide popup menu when page loads

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a javascript that when the mouse hovers above a link menu, it pops up a sub menu. It works except that the DIV for the sub menus popup when the page is loaded and i have to hover over and out to get rid of them. I want to be able to hide the DIV until i call it. Here's my code below.

```
 var timeout    = 0;
 var closetimer = 0;
 var ddmenuitem = 0;

  // open hidden layer
  function mopen(id)
 {  
// cancel close timer
mcancelclosetime();

// close old layer
if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

// get new layer and show it
ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

 }
 // close showed layer
 function mclose()
 {
     if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 }

 // go close timer
 function mclosetime()
 {
     closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
 }

 // cancel close timer
 function mcancelclosetime()
 {
     if(closetimer)
     {
         window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
         closetimer = null;
     }
 }

 // close layer when click-out
 document.onclick = mclose; 





      #m1 {
      background:#141414; 
      height:auto;
       width:300px;
       text-transform:capitalize; 
       font-size:13px;}




      <ul>
      <li> <a href="" onmouseover="mopen('m1')" 
         onmouseout="mclosetime()">About us</a> 
         <div id="m1" 
        onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" 
        onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Our History</a></li>

        </ul>
        </div></li>
```

Comment: Hide it using CSS  `display: block`

Comment: Use css `visibility: hidden;`